# How can i add multiple expand tile with checkbox list tile using Json in flutter

Tags: json, checkbox, flutter, expandablelistview, checkboxlist

this json has two data first only name and second is inside there also name which is service name. ex 'Travel and Stay' and 'Religious' is main name which has to be displayed in expansion tile name and The 'Church/ Baptism' and 'Hindu Temples' is a subitem which is displayed inside checkbox list tile. Hope you understand :slightly_smiling_face: Please Help me

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var lovCountryServices = [
    {
      "services": [
        {
          "service_group_id": 22,
          "service_category": "B",
          "name": "Air Tickets",
          "id": 228
        },
        {
          "service_group_id": 22,
          "service_category": "W",
          "name": "Boys Hostel",
          "id": 229
        },
      ],
      "name": "Travel and Stay",
      "is_active": true,
      "id": 22
    },
    {
      "services": [
        {
          "service_group_id": 19,
          "service_category": "B",
          "name": "Church/ Baptism",
          "id": 193
        },
        {
          "service_group_id": 19,
          "service_category": "B",
          "name": "Hindu Temples",
          "id": 194
        }
      ],
      "name": "Religious",
      "is_active": true,
      "id": 19
    }
  ];
  List<_Result> _results = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            itemCount: lovCountryServices.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              var item = lovCountryServices[index];
              var items= lovCountryServices[index]['services'];
              return ExpansionTile(
                title: Text(item['name']),
                children: <Widget>[
                  CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text("temp"),
                    value: item['is_active'],
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        item['is_active'] = val;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => print("sending to backend"),
            child: Text("SEND"),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

I want thw data in checkbox list tile right there is dummy data called TEMP and i want the data from json right now in json there is 'Boys Hostel' this data needs to comes inside the checkbox listtile. Hope you undestand please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Code: You can use a `Map` variable to store boolean value.

```
  Map<String, bool> _selection = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dummy'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            itemCount: lovCountryServices.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              var item =
                  lovCountryServices[index]; // should be outside build function
              List items = item['services']; // should be outside build function
              return ExpansionTile(
                title: Text(item['name']),
                children: List.generate(items.length, (i) {
                  _selection[items[i]['name']] =
                      _selection[items[i]['name']] ?? item['is_active'];
                  return CheckboxListTile(
                    title: Text(items[i]['name']),
                    value: _selection[items[i]['name']],
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selection[items[i]['name']] = val;
                      });
                    },
                  );
                }),
              );
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => print("sending to backend"),
            child: Text("SEND"),
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Dear, I appreciate your answer. but when i am expand the tile and select item from checkbox list tile either it will seleted all items or nothing selected. i want that user can select as per choice. Hope you understand, Please Help me

Comment: Hey Thank you so much, Dear :) You are awesome.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to format mobile number based on country code? Please Help me, Your answer will be appreciated

Comment: @RutvikGumasana  - ask as a different question for format mobile number based on country code.

Comment: **Yes i asked already please check it out in my profile and PLease Help Me :)**